# What determines which strings are interned and when?

Tags: python, string-interning

```
>>> s1 = "spam"
>>> s2 = "spam"
>>> s1 is s2
True
>>> q = 'asdalksdjfla;ksdjf;laksdjfals;kdfjasl;fjasdf'
>>> r = 'asdalksdjfla;ksdjf;laksdjfals;kdfjasl;fjasdf'
>>> q is r
False
```

How many characters should have to `s1 is s2` give `False`? Where is limit? i.e.  I am asking how long a string has to be before python starts making separate copies of it.

Comment: Are you asking how long a string has to be before python starts making separate copies of it?

Comment: It's completely implementation dependent and could change in the next version of Python without warning. Why do you want to know?

Comment: Yes, I am asking how long a string has to be before python starts making separate copies of it.

Comment: @Cris: What are you trying to accomplish? The behavior is implementation-defined and cannot be relied on. Why not just check for equality?

Comment: I just want know for knowing. Don't know that this is no important and very flexible.

Comment: if you just want to know, why don't you test it on the implementation *you*'re using?

Comment: if i will only testing i will never get knowledge that this is implementation dependent

Comment: Note that you may get a different result if you put your example statements in a script, instead of trying them interactively.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

String interning is implementation specific and shouldn't be relied upon, use equality testing if you want to check two strings are identical.

Comment: ...implementation specific. This is also answer. Thank You.

Comment: @Cris As a concrete example, [ideone's python version seems to intern your "long" strings](http://ideone.com/ZO3ni) as well as 1000-character-eval-constructed strings.

Comment: It gives me little more knowlednge and many more questions, byt it is ok.

Comment: So is there never a legit use case for users to test `s1 is s2` ?

Answer (score 12):

If you want, for some bizarre reason, to force the comparison to be true then use the intern function:

```
>>> a = intern('12345678012345678901234567890qazwsxedcrfvtgbyhnujmikolp')
>>> b = intern('12345678012345678901234567890qazwsxedcrfvtgbyhnujmikolp')
>>> a is b
True
```

Comment: For some bizarre reason, good to know.

Comment: Additionally, intern is moved into module sys in python 3000 along with id.  Also good to know.

Comment: For some reasons, the most. Could You tell is `intern()` only python 3000 toy?

Comment: @Cris `intern()` has been in Python at least since version 1.5

Comment: intern is in the root namespace.

Comment: It is built-in, you don't need to import anything.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a piece of comment about interned string from CPython 2.5.0 source file (stringobject.h)

```
/* ... ... This is generally restricted to strings that **"look like" Python identifiers**, although the intern() builtin can be used to force interning of any string ... ... */
```

Accordingly, strings contain only underscores, digits or alphabets will be interned. In your example, `q` and ``r contain `;`, so they will not be interned.