# 'is' operator behaves differently when comparing strings with spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators, object-identity

I've started learning Python (python 3.3) and I was trying out the `is` operator. I tried this:

```
>>> b = 'is it the space?'
>>> a = 'is it the space?'
>>> a is b
False
>>> c = 'isitthespace'
>>> d = 'isitthespace'
>>> c is d
True
>>> e = 'isitthespace?'
>>> f = 'isitthespace?'
>>> e is f
False
```

It seems like the space and the question mark make the `is` behave differently. What's going on?

**EDIT:** I know I should be using `==`, I just wanted to know why `is` behaves like this.

Comment: For the record you should be using `==` to compare any item for equality but this is an interesting question nonetheless

Comment: Probably some kind of string interning is causing `a is b` (noticing the string constant assigned to `b` has already been created and re-using it).  The interning rule must care about spaces (or possibly length)

Comment: Hmm... I have different results while using file instead of writing in interpreter. [The same in ideone.](http://ideone.com/o1Kovp)

Comment: For whatever reason `id('ab')` consistently returns the same value in my shell while `id('a ')` consistently changes.  I still have no idea why letters would have different behavior, but it's interesting to observe.  Perhaps Python makes some kind of optimization by assuming that strings will often contain letters?  I don't think that would make much sense but it's hard to explain this behavior. This is an interesting question.

Comment: I would still like to see a definitive answer to this regarding CPython

Comment: As you already know about  what `is` really does, maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622472/when-does-python-choose-to-intern-a-string) would be helpful - if it contained a useful answer.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476190/why-0-6-is-6-false

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*Warning: this answer is about the implementation details of a specific python interpreter. comparing strings with `is`==bad idea.*

Well, at least for cpython3.4/2.7.3, the answer is "no, it is not the whitespace". Not *only* the whitespace:

- Two string literals will share memory if they are either alphanumeric or reside on the same *block* (file, function, class or single interpreter command)
- An expression that evaluates to a string will result in an object that is identical to the one created using a string literal, if and only if it is created using constants and binary/unary operators, and the resulting string is shorter than 21 characters.
- Single characters are unique.

### Examples

Alphanumeric string literals always share memory:

```
>>> x='aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
>>> y='aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
>>> x is y
True
```

Non-alphanumeric string literals share memory if and only if they share the enclosing syntactic block:

(interpreter)

```
>>> x='`!@#$%^&*() \][=-. >:"?<a'; y='`!@#$%^&*() \][=-. >:"?<a';
>>> z='`!@#$%^&*() \][=-. >:"?<a';
>>> x is y
True 
>>> x is z
False
```

(file)

```
x='`!@#$%^&*() \][=-. >:"?<a';
y='`!@#$%^&*() \][=-. >:"?<a';
z=(lambda : '`!@#$%^&*() \][=-. >:"?<a')()
print(x is y)
print(x is z)
```

Output: `True` and `False`

For simple binary operations, the compiler is doing very simple constant propagation (see [peephole.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0a7d237c0919/Python/peephole.c)), but with strings it does so only if the resulting string is shorter than 21 charcters. If this is the case, the rules mentioned earlier are in force:

```
>>> 'a'*10+'a'*10 is 'a'*20
True
>>> 'a'*21 is 'a'*21
False
>>> 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' is 'aaaaaaaa' + 'aaaaaaaaaaaaa'
False
>>> t=2; 'a'*t is 'aa'
False
>>> 'a'.__add__('a') is 'aa'
False
>>> x='a' ; x+='a'; x is 'aa'
False
```

Single characters always share memory, of course:

```
>>> chr(0x20) is ' '
True
```

Comment: Probably then the strings are not interned as I thought before, but taken - as string literals - from the same pool of strings inside a module.

Comment: It is possible that when you hard-code `'a'*20`  (or addition of string literals) the interpreter makes an optimizing decision and replaces it with the resulting string `'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'`, so no string manipulation is done in runtime, (faster execution, but larger compiled code); but when the multiplication is too big the optimization does not activate, in to keep the code size small.

Comment: @lftah `dis.dis(lambda: 'x'*20)` results in `LOAD_CONST               3 ('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')`, `dis.dis(lambda: 'aaaaa' + "aaa")` in `LOAD_CONST               3 ('aaaaaaaa')`. I could imagine that a method call (e. g. `.join()` is "too complicated" in that sense.

Comment: BTW, `dis.dis(lambda: 'x'*21)` leads to `LOAD_CONST               1 ('x')` `LOAD_CONST               2 (21)` `BINARY_MULTIPLY`

Comment: Seems like the compiler is doing simple constant propagation, including '*' or '+' if the result is less than 21 characters.

Comment: What you show is only how this specific implementation behaves. In other words, it is only implementational detail, optimization, and it should not be considered the language feature. Think about the situation when the algorithm is to be distributed. The operator `is` should not be misused only because of the features of the implementation.

Comment: @pepr, we've been through this already. The implementation details are what is interesting here. We do not try to teach how to use python  in the correct way right now.

Comment: @Elazar: I see. Then, isn't it better to look inside the implementation?

Comment: @pepr you are more than welcome to look inside it and tell us. I found it easier for me to knock on the walls; but by all means - go ahead. Looking inside the implementation is indeed the right way to do it.

Comment: +1 great answer, In case someone is using **Ipython shell** then ``x='`!@#$%^&*() \][=-. >:"?<a'; y='`!@#$%^&*() \][=-. >:"?<a';`` will return `False`.

Comment: @Elazar: Great answer +1 :) Where did you find these informations. In which source file is this implemented?

Comment: Thanks. There's a link in the answer. But generally I just played with the REPL.

Answer (score 16):

To expand on Ignacio’s answer a bit: The `is` operator is the identity operator. It is used to compare *object* identity. If you construct two objects with the same contents, then it is usually not the case that the object identity yields true. It works for some small strings because CPython, the reference implementation of Python, stores the *contents* separately, making all those objects reference to the same string content. So the `is` operator returns true for those.

This however is an implementation detail of CPython and is generally neither guaranteed for CPython nor any other implementation. So using this fact is a bad idea as it can break any other day.

To compare strings, you use the `==` operator which compares the *equality* of objects. Two string objects are considered equal when they contain the same characters. So this is the correct operator to use when comparing strings, and `is` should be generally avoided if you do not *explicitely want* object *identity* (example: `a is False`).

---

If you are really interested in the details, you can find the implementation of CPython’s strings [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Objects/unicodeobject.c). But again: This is implementation detail, so you should *never* require this to work.

Comment: Anyone reading this using python 2.x should also be aware that they should not use `a is False`, as booleans aren't singletons.

Comment: @sapi not even python3 should do that

Comment: `a is False` makes no sense. The correct spelling is `not a`.

Comment: `a is False` is beautiful english. Apparently it is too good to be True :)

Comment: @LennartRegebro - you might want to compare two boolean expressions for equality though (in which case, `==` is correct).

Comment: @sapi: how about assuming Python 2.5 or later? My belief is that assuming this minimum version they are "singletons" (not the right word, but it'll do); is that really not so? Can you give an example?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan - type `False = True` into the shell; that's why comparing to `True` or `False` at all doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Ah yes, I suppose so---but that doesn't, of itself, mean `is True` or `is False` is a bad idea. If anyone does things like assigning to the names `False` or `True` they should *expect* things to break. If identity comparison with the names `True` and `False` is not sound, then assignation of the values `True` and `False` is similarly not sound.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: You should think more about it. The `a is False` *is* bad idea, indeed (independently on whether `False` and `True` are variables, constants, or keywords. From the linguistic/logical point of view, think about expressions like `if not ambiguous is False then...` (the `ambiguous` is a wrong identifier on its own). The `a is False` is the way of expressing a simple truth using rather complicated way. And this is not what should be done when programming.

Comment: @pepr: sure, I know that `is True` and `is False` will almost never be the right way of doing it, but my objection is to @sapi's original way of putting it, that the reason it shouldn't be used is that "booleans aren't singletons".

Comment: Yes. +1. Anyway, we should always go to the core of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

The `is` operator relies on the `id` function, which is `guaranteed to be unique among simultaneously existing objects.`  Specifically, `id` returns the object's memory address.  It seems that CPython has consistent memory addresses for strings containing only characters a-z and A-Z.

However, this seems to only be the case when the string has been assigned to a variable:

Here, the id of "foo" and the id of `a` are the same.  `a` has been set to "foo" prior to checking the id.

```
>>> a = "foo"
>>> id(a)
4322269384
>>> id("foo")
4322269384
```

However, the id of "bar" and the id of `a` are different when checking the id of "bar" prior to setting `a` equal to "bar".

```
>>> id("bar")
4322269224
>>> a = "bar"
>>> id(a)
4322268984
```

Checking the id of "bar" again *after* setting `a` equal to "bar" returns the same id.

```
>>> id("bar")
4322268984
```

So it seems that cPython keeps consistent memory addresses for strings containing only a-zA-Z when those strings are assigned to a variable.  It's also entirely possible that this is version dependent: I'm running python 2.7.3 on a macbook.  Others might get entirely different results.

Comment: I will be surprised if it is machine dependent. you probably mean "version dependent".

Answer (score 1):

In fact your code amounts to comparing objects id (i.e. their physical address). So instead of your is comparison:

```
>>> b = 'is it the space?'
>>> a = 'is it the space?'
>>> a is b
False
```

You can do:

```
>>> id(a) == id(b)
False
```

But, note that if a and b were directly in the comparison it would work.

```
>>> id('is it the space?') == id('is it the space?')
True
```

In fact, in an expression there's sharing between the same static strings. But, at the program scale there's only sharing for word-like strings (so neither spaces nor punctuations).

You should not rely on this behavior as it's not documented anywhere and is a detail of implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Two or more identical strings of consecutive alphanumeric (only) characters are stored in one structure, thus they share their memory reference.  There are posts about this phenomenon all over the internet since the 1990's.  It has evidently always been that way.  I have never seen a reasonable guess as to why that's the case.  I only know that it is.  Furthermore, if you split and re-join alphanumeric strings to remove spaces between words, the resulting identical alphanumeric strings do NOT share a reference, which I find odd. See below:

Add any non-alphanumeric value identically to both strings, and they instantly become copies, but not shared references.

```
a ="abbacca";  b = "abbacca";  a is b => True
a ="abbacca "; b = "abbacca "; a is b => False
a ="abbacca?"; b = "abbacca?"; a is b => False
```

~Dr. C.

Answer (score -1):

'is' operator compare the actual object.

`c is d` should also be false. My guess is that python make some optimization and in that case, it is the same object.

Comment: CPython keeps a pool of objects that are used frequently - short string literals and primitives like ints in the range 1-100. There is no reason to assume `c is d` should be false.

Comment: But on the other hand, one should *not* assume that `c is d` is true.

Comment: @Elazar my point exactly. The pool is an optimization and strings with space simply are out of the scope. @poke is righ, one should not assume that `c is d`

Comment: @jamylak I meant "at least", I did not know the exact range... thanks.

Comment: @creack obviously the OP is asking about these implementation details exactly. I assume he knows not to use them.