# Same value for id(float)

Tags: python

As far as I know, everything is object in Python and the **id()** should (am I right?) return a different number for each object.

In my case, `id(1)` returns `4298178968`, `id(2)` returns `4298178944` but I get the same values for all float types, `id(1.1)` returns `4298189032`, `id(2.2)` also returns `4298189032` and more.

Why I get the same **id** for all float values?

Answer (score 22):

Python can reuse memory positions.

When you run:

```
id(1.1)
```

you create a float value, ask for its `id()`, and then Python *deletes* the value again because nothing refers to it. When you then create *another* float value, Python can reuse the same memory position and thus `id(2.2)` is likely to return the same value for `id()`:

```
>>> id(1.1)
140550721129024
>>> id(2.2)
140550721129024
```

Do this instead:

```
float_one, float_two = 1.1, 2.2
print id(float_one), id(float_two)
```

Now the float values have references to them (the two variables) and won't be destroyed, and they now have different memory positions and thus `id()` values.

The reason you see different `id()` values for small integers (from -5 through to 256) is because [these values are interned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/python-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers); Python only creates *one* `1` integer object and re-uses it over and over again. As a result, these integers all have a unique memory address regardles, as the Python interpreter itself already refers to them, and won't delete them until the interpreter exits.

Comment: Ah yes, I was in ipython where the numbers are stored in Out! :)

Comment: Note that this interning of the small integers is probably a feature of the CPython _implementation_ rather than a guaranteed property of the language. In this case, it is similar to the small NSInteger values (0 through 12 from memory) in some Objective-C implementations where people have wondered about the strange retain counts. And, like that, it's probably not a good idea to rely on this interning.

Comment: @paxdiablo: the whole meaning of `id()` is a CPython implementation detail.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> id(1.1)
154154684
```

As 1.1 was not assigned to any variable so it is garbage collected and next time same id is going to be used for a float:

```
>>> id(2.2) 
154154684
```

save 1.1 in a variable:

```
>>> f = 1.1
>>> id(f)
154154684  #this id is locked for now
```

Now new address is used:

```
>>> id(1.1)
154154700
>>> id(2.2)
154154700
```

This applies to **integers** as well:

```
>>> id(260)
154302180
>>> id(280)
154302180
```

Integers from `-5` to `256` are actually cached in python, so they are always going to return different IDs.( ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/python-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers) )

For **strings**:

Like integers some strings are also cached in python. So, `id` of such strings is going to be different(For details  read : ['is' operator behaves differently when comparing strings with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16756699/is-operator-behaves-differently-when-comparing-strings-with-spaces) ):

```
>>> id('foo')
162861592
>>> id('foo')
162861568
```

Non-alphanumeric string(uses same `id`):

```
>>> id('foo!&9((&')
162840000
>>> id('foo!&9((&')
162840000
```