# id() of numpy.float64 objects are the same, even if their values differ?

Tags: python, numpy

I get the following:

```
import numpy
print id(numpy.float64(100)) ==  id(numpy.float64(10))
print numpy.float64(100) == numpy.float64(10)
```

gives:

```
True
False
```

Note that if I create the two float64 objects and then compare them then it appears to work as expected:

```
a = numpy.float64(10)
b = numpy.float64(100)
print a==b, id(a)==id(b)
```

gives:

```
False
False
```

Based on https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html shouldn't the id of two objects always differ if their values differ? How can I get the id to match if the values are different?

Is this some sort of bug in numpy?

Comment: This is fascinating. Same deal in Python 3: typing `id(numpy.float64(*))` into the interpreter, where `*` is a bunch of random numbers always prints the same thing.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17132047/270986

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a quirk of memory reuse rather than a NumPy bug.

The line

```
id(numpy.float64(100)) == id(numpy.float64(10))
```

first creates a float `numpy.float64(100)` and then calls the `id` function on it. This memory is then immediately freed by Python's garbage collector because there are no more references to it. The memory slot is free to be reused by any new objects that are created.

When `numpy.float64(10)` is created, it occupies the same memory location, hence the memory addresses returned by `id` compare equal.

---

This chain of events is perhaps clearer when you look at the bytecode:

```
>>> dis.dis('id(numpy.float64(100)) ==  id(numpy.float64(10))')
  0 LOAD_NAME                0 (id)
  3 LOAD_NAME                1 (numpy)
  6 LOAD_ATTR                2 (float64)
  9 LOAD_CONST               0 (100)
 12 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair) # call numpy.float64(100)
 15 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair) # get id of object

 # gc runs and frees memory occupied by numpy.float64(100)

 18 LOAD_NAME                0 (id)                   
 21 LOAD_NAME                1 (numpy)
 24 LOAD_ATTR                2 (float64)
 27 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
 30 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair) # call numpy.float64(10)
 33 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair) # get id of object

 36 COMPARE_OP               2 (==) # compare the two ids 
 39 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Good point, I agree that this is most likely the reason for this behaviour. Thinking a bit further, I tried to validate this by turning off gc with "gc.disable()" but this still gave the same behaviour, and even "gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_SAVEALL)" wasn't enough to keep the first float64 from being collected. Is there some other garbage collector that could be turned off?

Comment: Some other garbage collector: yes. That can be turned off: no. The gc module controls the cyclic garbage collector that runs on top of the regular reference-counting based gc; there's no way to turn off the basic reference-counting based gc.

Answer (score 4):

Imagine that you put a book on a shelf, and then someone notices that you're not using it and takes the book off the shelf to free some space.  You then move to put a different book on the shelf at a convenient location.

If you suddenly realize that you had two different books at the very same location, do you think there's a bug in reality? ;-)

After you call `id` on `numpy.float64(100)`, you have no way to refer to that float object you made, and so the interpreter is perfectly free to reuse that id.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id), the `id()` function is described like this

> id(object)
>
> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer (or
>   long integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this
>   object during its lifetime. **Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes
>   may have the same id() value.**

So that may happen, but not necessarily always. As they do not exist simultaneously in time, they end up catching the same `id`.

However, in this case

```
a = numpy.float64(10)
b = numpy.float64(100)
print a==b, id(a)==id(b)
```

They **do** exist simultaneously, so they **cannot** have the same `id`.