# Python: what difference between 'is' and '=='?

Tags: python

I'm trying next code:

```
x = 'asd'
y = 'asd'
z = input() #write here string 'asd'. For Python 2.x use raw_input()
x == y # True.
x is y # True.
x == z # True.
x is z # False.
```

Why we have false in last expression?

Comment: For small strings part: [`is` operator behaves differently when comparing strings with spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16756699/is-operator-behaves-differently-when-comparing-strings-with-spaces)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The title is misleading, but I think it is specifically about why the inputted string is not the same. It also does not contain a space, as in the other question.

Comment: The question may be slightly different, but the answers are the same-- `is` sometimes works, coincidentally, as an implementation detail in cpython. The fact that input is involved isn't particularly special; the takeaway should be to never use `is`.

Comment: This is exactly what I came for

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`is` checks for *identity*. `a is b` is `True` iff `a` and `b` are the same object (they are both stored in the same memory address).

`==` checks for *equality*, which is usually defined by the magic method `__eq__` - i.e., `a == b` is `True` if `a.__eq__(b)` is `True`.

In your case specifically, Python optimizes the two hardcoded strings into the same object (since strings are immutable, there's no danger in that). Since `input()` will create a string at runtime, it can't do that optimization, so a new string object is created.

Comment: --input() will create a string at runtime
x = 5
y = int(input()) # << 5
x == y #True
x is y #True!
But y is created at runtime too.

Answer (score 3):

`is` checks not if the object are equal, but if the objects are actually the same object. Since `input()` always creates a new string, it never `is` another string.

Python creates one object for all occurrences of the same string literal, that's why `x` and `y` point to the same object.

Comment: i love the "it never `is`"