# Query on Name & object in Python

Tags: python

In Interactive mode of python, When i say,

```
>>> mystr = 'abc'
```

we have object created in the current frame of type `string` with content `'abc'`

Now, If i change the binding of `mystr` as shown below,

```
>>> mystr = 'def'
```

then, the name `mystr` will bind to a new object with the content `'def'`.

We know that string are immutable objects, so object containing `'abc'` gets unaffected.

In my machine it works like this:

```
>>> mystr = 'abc'
>>> id(mystr)
30868568
>>> mystr = 'def'
>>> id(mystr)
36585632
>>> mystr = 'abc'
>>> id(mystr)
30868568
```

My question:

How does Python environment deal with object containing 'abc' after new binding, Will it purged?

Comment: This is an implementation detail, but in CPython, small strings are interned and `"abc"` won't be deleted when your reference is gone. (By the way, never name a variable `str`, as it shadows the builtin type object...)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622472/when-does-python-choose-to-intern-a-string might be helpful.

Comment: you are right martijn

Comment: @MartijnPieters After i read your answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245324/about-the-changing-id-of-a-python-immutable-string), I doubt , if this is the reason  `Python can then perhaps reuse the same memory location for a new string object, if you re-run the same code.` . It could not be for my above case. i think `abc` is sitting in some common pool and then being re-used like java, which wooble pointed above

Comment: @overexchange: `abc` is interned there, it qualified as a identifier string (letters, digits and underscores only).

Comment: @MartijnPieters so why did you tag my question as already answered here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245324/about-the-changing-id-of-a-python-immutable-string)?

Comment: @overexchange: because my answer there explains in exhaustive detail all the ways CPython can end up reusing a string object.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes you are right, what about purging part Does unused string(`abc`) stay forever?

Comment: @overexchange: interned string objects stay around until the interpreter shuts down. Non-interned string literals stay around as long as the code object stays around; for the most part that means the module the function was defined in stays around until Python shuts down, so the code object and the constant stay around until then too.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are mutable, references are not.

When you assign `str` to `"def"`, the other string `"abc"` does not affects. Just `str`'s content will change, and it will reference to new `"def"` object.

When you manipulate strings in python, java etc.. languages such taking substring, it will make a new string object.

-For extra information (performance tips) if you work with strings for manipulating them use `StringBuilder`.

Comment: OP already knows that strings are immutable in Python, and is only asking about what happens to the immutable string that's no longer referenced. And StringBuilder isn't even a Python thing; I have no idea why you'd mention Java at all. -1.

Comment: As I said It does not referenced from str. If no one reference it any more to it will destroy by garbage collection.