# python read json file into a dictionary can't use 'is' keyword for comparing string values

Tags: json, string, python-3.x

I am using `json.load()` to read a `json` config file into a dictionary, but I couldn't use `is` keyword for comparing string values.

```
config = json.load(open(config_file))
if config['some_key'] is 'abc':
# code block
```

even the value of `config['some_key']` is `abc`, the `if` block is passed somehow. But if I changed the code to,

```
if config['some_key'] == 'abc':
# code block
```

the `if` code body will get executed. I am wondering what is the issue. Since `string` is a `python` object, so should be no problem using `is` for value comparison.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When does python choose to intern a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622472/when-does-python-choose-to-intern-a-string)

Comment: don't use `is` to compare strings...