# Why Python "is" operator gives different result for variable containing same string

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-keyword, identity-operator

When i am trying to compare the identity of two variable containing same string, python gives me different result.

```
msg = "hello world"
new_msg = "hello world"

print( msg is new_msg )
> False
```

But,

```
msg = "hello_world"
new_msg = "hello_world"

print( msg is new_msg )
> True
```

Comment: Python doesn't promise to be consistent here, because the identity of a string should never matter. If it mattered, there would be a consistent rule.

Comment: "Why Python “is” operator gives different result for variable containing same string" Why do you expect those objects to have the same identity?

Comment: For your implementation of Python, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23556366) seems to be the cause.